# Using WifiManager to connect to a wireless network (wpa2)

Tags: java, android, wifi, nfc, wifimanager

Trying to create a NFC tag app that stores Wifi credentials on a NFC tag then read it out. From there I take the string and use that to and put the credentials through wifimanager to connect to the wireless network. I'm pretty sure I have the code correct, but it's still not connecting. Am i missing something? The channel i'm trying to connect to is WPA2.

How i'm pulling the data for the function:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String payload = _textViewData.getText().toString();
            String[] parts = payload.split("-");
            String SSID = parts[0];
            String Password = parts[1];

            part1.setText(SSID);
            part2.setText(Password);
            connectToWifi(SSID, Password);

        }
    });
```

UPDATED: connect function

```
 private void connectToWifi(final String networkSSID, final String networkPassword){
    if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", networkSSID);
    conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPassword +"\"";

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

    List<WifiConfiguration> wifiList = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for( WifiConfiguration i : wifiList ) {
        if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
            wifiManager.disconnect();
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
            wifiManager.reconnect();

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2:

I switched my network to WPA and it worked, doesn't seem to work for WPA2, is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For connecting  WPA network you need to add passphrase like this:

```
conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";
```

For Open network you need to do this:

```
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
```

Then, you need to add it to Android wifi manager settings:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
```

after that you have to enable it.

```
List<WifiConfiguration> wifiList = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for( WifiConfiguration i : wifiList ) {
            if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
                 wifiManager.disconnect();
                 wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                wifiManager.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;                                         
wifiManager.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);                                           
wifiManager.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);                                           
wifiManager.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);                                            
wifiManager.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);                                           wifiManager.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);                                        wifiManager.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);                                          wifiManager.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
                 wifiManager.reconnect();               

                 break;
            }           
         }
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: hmmm still isn't working, please check my updated connected function to see if I implemented what you were saying correctly. Also, I had this `wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);` at the top of my OnCreate function, so wasn't sure if i should add your `WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); ` or not, but I did.

Comment: @PaulCabz i update the code please check. i was same code that was working fine, for WPA2 you have to read official dosument. hope it work.thanks.

Comment: most of these calls to wifiManager should be made on a WifiConfiguration.

Comment: How can I connect to the wpa3 network? pls kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @HemantParmar

With his help and a bit of googling I got it to work with WPA2:

```
private void connectToWifiWPA2(final String networkSSID, final String networkPassword){
    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
    conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPassword +"\"";

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    //if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
    //    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    //}
    conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);

    int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
    wifiManager.disconnect();
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
    wifiManager.reconnect();
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! After hours of searching and trying dozens of other solutions, i finally found this and it worked! Thanks a million.